# How to get the missing Edit and Open items in context menu for Visio drawing in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, context-menu, microsoft-visio

On two different PC with Windows 10 bit, I have MS Office Professional Plus 2016 and MS Visio Standard 2016, and both are fully updated for Windows and Office.

In the same Word document with an embedded Visio drawing, I try to open the Visio drawing from Word, using the right click context menu.

On one of the PCs, this gives a context menu for Visio with Edit and Open, as shown below.

[image]

But on the other PC, this gives a context menu for Visio without Edit and Open, as shown below.

[image]

It appears that others have encountered this problem also, as shown in [this MS forum link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/opening-embedded-visio-drawins-in-word-2016/4d0df1f0-b03f-4a1b-abda-a1d5b48cd233), which presents a workaround, but no solution for how to get the missing Edit and Open in the Visio context menu.

Any suggestions for how to get the Edit and Open items in the context menu?

***Update based on answer from Keith Miller***

The PC that works has extra items in the Registry for .vsd extension, where the items are seen on the figure below.

[image]

The PC that is missing the menu only have the OpenWithProgids.  Unfortunately I can not experiment with the Registry to try and find it, so I live with the workaround using alt and double click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you have the options on one computer but not the other makes me think this may be an "**Open With**" issue. If I'm correct, you'll find that the computer without the menu items has a **UserChoice** registry key for Visio files & the working computer doesn't.

The relevant registry key is:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.vsd\UserChoice
```

If it exists on the problem machine, delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The problem machine do **not** have the UserChoice, where the machine that works does; so other way around.  I have updated the question with image from the working machine.

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, it appear to be a issue with the Visio 2016 integration into word.

So far there doesn't seem to be a good way to solve this problem.

You can refer to a similar situation below, using Visio 2016 some users encounter similar problems:

[Word 2016 Embedded Visio Object](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-2016-embedded-visio-object/74d6f864-103e-44b8-a420-154e1ff0e81c?page=1)

Here's what mike's done tests:

[image]

If circumstances permit, it is recommended that you use Visio2013.

Comment: Thanks for the addition; interesting to see that others got the problem too.